# Can I execute commands from a midnight commander ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, mc

When I connect to a VPS via a Shell link in MC, the location of the command prompt remains at my local box. I would like to be able to execute commands (e.g. mkdir, tar/untar) directly from the location of the left or right panel. I could ssh into the VPS separately, but this is not as handy as how I can use SFTP in Total Commander under Windows: e.g. type a command on my local machine in the left panel, switch to the right panel (remote location) using tab and directly type a command that is executed at the remote location.

Is this possible with Midnight Commander?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

> the fact that the link uses a remote shell is abstracted away by the VFS layer, so: no. 
>   http://gnome-apps.13852.n7.nabble.com/Execute-command-on-a-shell-link-td63584.html